# clickable sidebar markerclusterer google map api v.3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sidebar, markerclusterer

Google map API v.3 is used.
Attached with markerclusterer.js

I would like to make a map that show the cluster of markers. (Done!)

When I click on the marker, an infowindow would be shown. (Done!)

A sidebar is made next to the map. When click on it, an infowindow would be shown for relevant marker. (Failed, why?)

Please help me take a look at the code of javascript and html.

```
var hk_markers = [
{
'id':1,
'name':'Sanrio Puroland(サンリオピューロランド)',
'location':'Tokyo, Japan',
'lat':35.62464,
'lng':139.42916,
},
{
'id':2,
'name':'Harmonyland(ハーモニーランド)',
'location':'Oita, Japan',
'lat':33.40162,
'lng':131.54657,
},
{
'id':3,
'name':'Sanrio Hello Kitty Town',
'location':'Johor, Malaysia',
'lat':1.41385,
'lng':103.66031,
},
{
'id':4,
'name':'China Hello Kitty Park(浙江安吉凯蒂猫家园)',
'location':'Zhejiang, China',
'lat':30.62377,
'lng':119.73663,
},
{
'id':5,
'name':'Hello Kitty Go Green Organic Farm (Hello Kitty有機薈低碳農莊)',
'location':'near Kam Sheung Road MTR Station, West Rail Line, Yuen lng, the New Territories, Hong Kong',
'lat':22.43402,
'lng':114.06037,
},
{
'id':6,
'name':'Jeju Hello Kitty Island - Museum & Cafe (헬로키티아일랜드)',
'location':'340, Hanchang-ro, Andeok-myeon, Seogwipo, Jeju-do, South Korea',
'lat':33.29021,
'lng':126.35205,
},
{
'id':7,
'name':'Dubai Hello Kitty Beauty Spa (مرحبا كيتي الجمال سبا)',
'location':'Jumeirah town centre, Jumeirah Beach Road, Dubai, the United Arab Emirates',
'lat':25.21491,
'lng':55.25100,
},];

var map;

var myCentreLat = 22.3700556;
var myCentreLng = 114.1535941;

var initialZoom = 2;
var markers = [];
var markerCluster;

var side_bar_html = ""; 



function showAll(){

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



for (var i = 0; i <hk_markers.length; i++) {

    var myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(hk_markers[i].lat,hk_markers[i].lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPos,
        map: map
    });

    var info = hk_markers[i].name;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(hk_markers[i].name);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    markers.push(marker);

    side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript: myclick('+ (markers.length-1) +')">' + '<p style="font-size:10px">' + hk_markers[i].name + '<\/p>' + '<\/a>';    

}
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


}

function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], "click");
}




function initialize() {

var myDest = new google.maps.LatLng(myCentreLat,myCentreLng);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: initialZoom,
    center: myDest,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

showAll();
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
markers=[];

}
```

Here is the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="hkmarkersetup2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>



</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<h2>Testing</h2>



<table border=1>
<td>
<div class="gmap" id="map_canvas" style="height: 450px; width: 900px"></div>
</td>
<td width = 450>
<div class ="wrap" id="side_bar" style="overflow:auto; height:450px"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing the markers array after setting up all the sidebar entries to use it:

```
showAll();
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
markers=[];
```

Don't do that.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9bap1xeq/)

code snippet:

```js
var hk_markers = [{
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'Sanrio Puroland(サンリオピューロランド)',
        'location': 'Tokyo, Japan',
        'lat': 35.62464,
        'lng': 139.42916,
}, {
    'id': 2,
        'name': 'Harmonyland(ハーモニーランド)',
        'location': 'Oita, Japan',
        'lat': 33.40162,
        'lng': 131.54657,
}, {
    'id': 3,
        'name': 'Sanrio Hello Kitty Town',
        'location': 'Johor, Malaysia',
        'lat': 1.41385,
        'lng': 103.66031,
}, {
    'id': 4,
        'name': 'China Hello Kitty Park(浙江安吉凯蒂猫家园)',
        'location': 'Zhejiang, China',
        'lat': 30.62377,
        'lng': 119.73663,
}, {
    'id': 5,
        'name': 'Hello Kitty Go Green Organic Farm (Hello Kitty有機薈低碳農莊)',
        'location': 'near Kam Sheung Road MTR Station, West Rail Line, Yuen lng, the New Territories, Hong Kong',
        'lat': 22.43402,
        'lng': 114.06037,
}, {
    'id': 6,
        'name': 'Jeju Hello Kitty Island - Museum & Cafe (헬로키티아일랜드)',
        'location': '340, Hanchang-ro, Andeok-myeon, Seogwipo, Jeju-do, South Korea',
        'lat': 33.29021,
        'lng': 126.35205,
}, {
    'id': 7,
        'name': 'Dubai Hello Kitty Beauty Spa (مرحبا كيتي الجمال سبا)',
        'location': 'Jumeirah town centre, Jumeirah Beach Road, Dubai, the United Arab Emirates',
        'lat': 25.21491,
        'lng': 55.25100,
}, ];

var map;

var myCentreLat = 22.3700556;
var myCentreLng = 114.1535941;

var initialZoom = 2;
var markers = [];
var markerCluster;

var side_bar_html = "";



function showAll() {

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



    for (var i = 0; i < hk_markers.length; i++) {

        var myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(hk_markers[i].lat, hk_markers[i].lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myPos,
            map: map
        });

        var info = hk_markers[i].name;

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(hk_markers[i].name);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        markers.push(marker);

        side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript: myclick(' + (markers.length - 1) + ')">' + '<p style="font-size:10px">' + hk_markers[i].name + '<\/p>' + '<\/a>';

    }
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


}

function myclick(i) {
    // zoom to marker so added to map
    map.setCenter(markers[i].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(19);
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], "click");
}




function initialize() {

    var myDest = new google.maps.LatLng(myCentreLat, myCentreLng);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: initialZoom,
        center: myDest,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    showAll();
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
    // markers = [];
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<h2>Testing</h2>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="gmap" id="map_canvas" style="height: 450px; width: 450px"></div>
        </td>
        <td width="450">
            <div class="wrap" id="side_bar" style="overflow:auto; height:450px"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```